# Npm init not working / Please try running this command again as root/Administrator

Tags: node.js

I want to init a node.js jason file. I navigated to node_modules and typed in npm init, but as soon as I execute it and try to create the file i get an error (look below). I know what causes the error (no admin rights) but not how to fix it. I tried cleaning my cache too. I have windows 10 and whenever I type in sudo chown it says that this command doen´s exist. Thanks in advance!

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "init"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\package.json
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\package.json'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\package.json'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\package.json' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "init"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm-debug.log.897946660
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm-debug.log.897946660'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm-debug.log.897946660'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm-debug.log.897946660' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to run `npm init` in the `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules` directory. Maybe go to your home directory or any other directory that you have access to, create a new subdirectory there, `cd` into it and run `npm init` from there. Because `npm init` has to be able to create `package.json` file in a directory that you run it in.